# Core Data. Get entity with max "dateTime" which is written as string?

Tags: ios, datetime, core-data, comparison, type-conversion

Currently I get all the entities of this type and search for max value via for-each cycle.

I use `NSFetchRequest` with `NSPredicate` as param.

Is it possible to find this entity via one core data request only? As I understand this request should contain a conversion to a date and date comparison.

Comment: So your date is stored as a string? (Why?) What format is used?

Comment: And what does your current code look like?

Comment: Approximate format used: "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss" (all the data components are numbers). Yes, Core Data stores it as "String". Why? This application is cross-platform and it is better to change the tables'/entities' relations as less as possible. But do you know at least how to compare datetime objects?

Comment: I strongly assume that you cannot do it directly in the fetch request, since the sort descriptors for a Core Data fetch request are very limited. - If the format were "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" then a simple string comparison would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you'll need a trick somewhere.

If the string format would be like yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss you could do this easily with a sort descriptor. Since you are using the format MM/dd/yyyy this will not work, since it will sort with months first.

<s>However, you can create a category on your managed object which adds an NSDate property, which dynamically converts your string dates into real dates. In your sort descriptor you can then use this category field, sort descending and pick the first result.</s>
EDIT: NSSortDescriptors cannot be used with transient properties, so this is not an option. (See also Martin R's comment below).

Another option would be to add an extra date field to your entity, which stores the same date in real date-format. Therefore you would need to update your current database model, but this would probably perform slightly better.

To clarify the last option:
(Assuming you have added a date field called: 'realDateTime')

When storing the entities you can add the following code:

```
// String to date conversion
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
realDateTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTime];
```

To find the entity with the most recent date, you can implement a method which looks something like this:

```
- (NSManagedObject *)findObjectMostRecentDate {
    // Set a sort descriptor to set last date as first result
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"realDateTime" ascending:NO]]];

    // Execute the fetch request
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if (results.count) {
        return [results firstObject]; // <-- This returns the object with the 'max' date
    else
        return nil; // No objects fetched
}
```

Comment: A Core Data sort descriptor can *only* use persistent properties, no transient properties and no Objective-C methods. Therefore your first suggestion does not work.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction. I was pretty sure that i've done that in the past, but it seems you are right, so i must be wrong ;). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Anyways adding the second dateTime field is better than replacing the existing one. If I do this then how to compare dateTime format?

Comment: I've added some example code to my answer. You don't need an explicit dateTime compare since this will be done by the sort operation.